# File permissions for a process in C

Tags: c, file-permissions

If a process where to create a file and closes it:

```
void function_procA (void) {
    FILE *G_fp = NULL;

    G_fp = fopen("/var/log/file.log", "w");
    fclose(G_fp);
}
```

could another process open a pointer to that file and start writing to it?

```
void function_procB (void) {
    FILE *G_fp = NULL;

    G_fp = fopen("/var/log/file.log", "w");
    fprintf(G_fp, "Hello, World!\n");
    fclose(G_fp);
}
```

In short: what are file permissions between different processes? And if only one process gets exclusive right to write to the file by default, how do I change the permissions such that the other process has rights to write to it?

Thanks.

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 2):

That would become a data-race.

Can be avoided very easily with file locking:

```
#include <sys/file.h>

flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_SH); // shared lock for reading
flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_EX); // exlusive lock
flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_UN); // release lock
```

Above example works on linux, no idea about windows, though. The `flock` is just a wrapper for `fcntl` system call.

Answer (score 0):

If both process are ran by the same user it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems) has a good description.

Quoting:

> Unix-like operating systems (including Linux and Apple's OS X) do not
>   normally automatically lock open files or running programs. Several
>   kinds of file-locking mechanisms are available in different flavors of
>   Unix, and many operating systems support more than one kind for
>   compatibility. The two most common mechanisms are fcntl(2) and
>   flock(2). A third such mechanism is lockf(3), which may be separate or
>   may be implemented using either of the first two primitives. Although
>   some types of locks can be configured to be mandatory, file locks
>   under Unix are by default advisory. This means that cooperating
>   processes may use locks to coordinate access to a file among
>   themselves, but uncooperative processes are also free to ignore locks
>   and access the file in any way they choose. In other words, file locks
>   lock out other file lockers only, not I/O.